# How to set a different terminal profile for debugpy in VSCode for macOS?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rosetta-2, debugpy

I've seen [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/z5qt2c/possible_to_use_nondefault_terminal_profile_for/), but I don't know how this could help me. What I want to do is to start the debugger within a Rosetta terminal. What I currently do, is start the script in debug mode till it fails and then I type `arch -x86_64 zsh` to enter Rosetta2 emulation. Then I restart the debugger and then it works. How can I tell debugpy to immediately start with a Rosetta2 emulation?

I have added this to my `settings.json`:

```
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
        "x86_64 zsh": {
            "path": "arch",
            "args": [
                "-arch", "x86_64", "zsh"
            ]
        }
    }
```

and I can use this as a normal terminal. But how do I select this for debugpy?

For debugpy within VSCode I switch to the `Run and debug` view an create a `launch.json` as shown below:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: appName.py",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/abs/path/to/appName.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I hit the start debugging button as shown in this screenshot:
[image]
After that a debug terminal opens and fails since it is running on `arm64`. If I manually switch this terminal to `x86_64` and hit the run and debug button again, it works.

Comment: there are [several ways of using debugpy in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) which way are you using?

Comment: I’m using it the „default“ way. So I created a basic `launch.json` and run it using the start debugging button in the run & debug view.

Comment: Sorry, I’m on the tablet right now. Will update the question as soon as I am back on the Mac. Hope this `launch.json` helps.

Comment: can you just run VS Code itself with Rosetta?

Comment: Tried to try that. That makes VSCode incredibly slow. And I would need to install the `universal2` app rather then the `arm64`. And it seems to be working even with this setup. Just not right from the start.

Answer (score 0):

### Try the following solution

> use `automationProfile`

settings.json

```js
{
  // for tasks and debug
  "terminal.integrated.automationProfile.osx": {
    "path": "/bin/sh",
    "args": [
        "-arch", "x86_64", "zsh"
    ]
  }
}
```

### refs

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles#_configuring-the-taskdebug-profile

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics#_terminal-shells

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_console

Answer (score 0):

xgqfrms' answer sounds to me to be on the right track with usage of the `terminal.automationProfile.<platform>` settings, but I'm pretty sure `arch` needs to be the wrapper program, which I'm assuming would look something more along the lines of this:

```json
"terminal.integrated.automationProfile.osx": {
    "path": "arch", // full path might be needed
    "args": ["-arch", "x86_64", "zsh"],
},
```